How to iterate i18n array inside json in nextjs?
I am building a grid box with 6 items that it need to be translated using i18n however I noticed that my code and common.json are breaking up with features arrays of objects to retrieve that to translate. what's the best way to do this without refactoring my code less dynamically?
    const data = [
          {
            id: 1,
            icon: icon1,
            titleKey: 'whatToExpect.features[0].title',
            descriptionKey: 'whatToExpect.features[0].description'
          },
        ];

const WhatToExpect = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation('common');

  return (
    <Box sx={styles.features}>
    {data.map((item) => (
      <Feature
        className="feature-item"
        key={item.id}
        data={{
          icon: item.icon,
          title: t(item.titleKey),
          description: t(item.descriptionKey)
        }}
      />
    ))}
  </Box>
  );

common.json
{
      "whatToExpect": {
        "span": "What to Expect",
        "features": [
          {
            "title": "dfdfdfdf",
            "description": "lorem shshs3h"
          },
          {
            "title": "sdsdsdsd",
            "description": "dff4bjgd3jgj4343y."
          },
        ]
      }
    }


What is the t function here?

I updated the code

Does whatToExpect.features.0.title work?

it works. it was something like cache issues

...what does this have to do with functional programming? Please don't include tags that don't match the question. You can preview a what a tag is for by hovering over it in the UI. I removed the functional programming tag.
